# Error in Foursquare API

Tags: php, foursquare

I'm currently working with the foursquare API. I downloaded the files from github right here https://github.com/jmathai/foursquare-async. But, when I put my credentials in like my clientId, my client secret, and my redirectUri, it doesn't quite work; it says that there's a redirect uri mismatch. The beginning of the code in the simpleTest.php file looks like this:

```
ob_start();
require_once 'EpiCurl.php';
require_once 'EpiFoursquare.php';
$clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
$clientSecret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
$code = 'CODE';
$accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
$redirectUri = 'http://www.thered-line.com/foursquare/simpleTest.php';
$userId = '4855602';
$fsObj = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret, $accessToken);
$fsObjUnAuth = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret);
```

How to get my $code and $accessToken... ?

Answer (score 1):

This library is for using Foursquare with oAuth. That means that you get your code and access token from part of the oAuth handshake. Foursquare provided you with the client information - the rest is done in the oauth handshake.

When you changed the URL and the user, but kept the code and access token from the original test, you ended up with a code and token that were invalid - you are using the tokens from a handshake that does not have the same data anymore. If you change the test back to how it was on Github, it should run.

Basically, all you need for this lib is the clientID and the Secret - the rest will be done with PHP function calls from the library.

[More info](https://github.com/jmathai/foursquare-async/wiki#tokens)

Comment: Okay, so how do I start a new test so that the credentials are unique to me?

Comment: To test with the credentials unique to you, you would need to build a full test (with the functions, etc.) The purpose of this test appears to be to make sure that PHP/cURL is set up right, and that communication is flowing, and the handshake works.

Comment: For that, follow the ["Obtaining Access Tokens"](https://github.com/jmathai/foursquare-async/wiki#usage_and_examples) section. You are going to have to build a mini application to test that everything is working with your credentials.

Comment: That being said, if their test with their credentials run, you are ok. If you copy your client id and secret correctly, the rest is all handled by the lib. I would just try building something simple (click a button to auth, then display checkin number) rather than worrying about trying to make a test.